Convergence of Euler-Maruyama scheme in total variation, uniformly over time
Consider the SDE
$$X(t) = X(0) + \int_0^t f(X(s))ds+ \int_0^t g(X(s-))dZ(s) \quad t\in [0,T]$$
where $f: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$, $g: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$ are Lipschitz functions, and where $Z$ is a semimartingale. Let $X^n$ denote the Euler-Maruyama scheme with step size $T/n$.
I'm looking for a result of the form
$$|\mathbb{E}[h(X^n(t)) - h(X(t))]| \leq C (T/n)^\alpha \quad t\in [0,T]$$
for some $C>0, \alpha>0$ which don't depend on $t$, for every bounded measurable $h:\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$.
(This is equivalent to a bound on the total variation distance between the laws of $X^n(t)$ and $X(t)$.)
Looking into some literature, I found the following special cases:

Suo et al. (2020) with $f$ possibly discontinuous, $g$ a constant matrix and $Z$ a Brownian motion.
Bally and Talay (1996) with $Z$ a Brownian motion, giving a bound for the terminal value $|\mathbb{E}[h(X^n(T)) - h(X(T))]|$.
Bencheikh and Jourdain (2020) with $f$ possibly discontinuous, $g$ a constant matrix and $Z$ a Brownian motion, giving a bound for the value $|\mathbb{E}[h(X^n(kT/n)) - h(X(kT/n))]|$ uniformly over $k=0,...,n$.
Clément (2022) with $Z$ pure jump-type Lévy, also giving a bound for the value $|\mathbb{E}[h(X^n(kT/n)) - h(X(kT/n))]|$ uniformly over $k=0,...,n$.

Suo et al is already quite helpful, but I'd like to find a result for more general SDEs. To get a better understanding of the result I'm looking for, I have the following questions:

Do bounds on time points $kT/n$ or at terminal time $T$ say something about the error at arbitrary $t\in [0,T]$?
The mentioned literature seems to look for specific values of $C$ and $\alpha$, with $\alpha$ as high as possible to have a quick convergence rate. In my case, I don't care about the specific value of $C$ and $\alpha$, any convergence rate will do. Does anyone know whether such work exists? Or would one require more regularity of $f,g$ or $Z$ for such convergence to even hold uniformly over $t$?

Thanks in advance!
